# Using Python client for Prometheus on IPv6

Tags: python, prometheus, ipv6, ipv4, prometheus-python-client

I am writing a custom exporter for my application using the official [Python client for Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) My code works fine with the below snippet, (I'm redacting the rest of the code as I think it is irrelevant to the issue I'm facing.)

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge
start_http_server(9669)
```

I'm able to get the response if I do

```
curl --noproxy "*" -v http://localhost:9669/metrics
```

from the same machine. The issue here is my servers on IPv6. So this endpoint is not reachable from the server where I have Prometheus running. How can make

```
start_http_server
```

on IPv6 or is there a workaround for this?

I tried running a flask app and doing curl from the machine where I have Prometheus installed. I do not get response for

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8989)
```

but I get response if I modify the line to

```
app.run(host='::', port=8989)
```

So I figured I need to run the Prometheus

```
start_http_server
```

on IPv6. I tried

```
start_http_server(9669, addr='[::]')
```

but I get the error

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

and for

```
start_http_server(9669, addr='::')
```

I get the error

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an old version of the Python Prometheus client.

I tried the most recent version 0.19.0 with Python 3.8, and this code is working just fine for me (server listens on IPv6):

```py
from prometheus_client import start_http_server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(9999, addr='::')
    while True:
        pass
```

According to a Google search, your bug ("Address family for hostname not supported") was reported [here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/567), fixed [in this PR](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/pull/657), and then released in 0.14.0 from April 2022.